# How to enter input to .exe file through command prompt on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, exe, command-prompt

I have a .exe file that I have built from the makefile of a set of source .cpp files. 
It should take in a set of inputs and write the output to a .txt file. The manual I am following provides the following instruction for running it on linux:

```
./xyz -l4 -w6 -k4 -iSampleInputTJU.txt -oMyOutputFile.txt -p
```

But I need to run it on windows 10. So I typed in:

```
C:>\Desktop\xyz -l4 -w6 -k4 -iSampleInputTJU.txt -oMyOutputFile.txt -p
```

However it tells me that it cannot open the input file. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Please help. Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the path?

Comment: Without knowing what this program is there is no way to tell. Different programs do things differently.

Comment: This might be a typo in your question, but shouldn't it be `C:\Desktop\xyz -l4 -w6 -k4 -iSampleInputTJU.txt -oMyOutputFile.txt -p`. And are you sure that there is a Desktop folder in C drive containing the text file?

Comment: If you don't specify the full path of a file (c:\foo\bar\baz.txt) then it uses the default directory.  Which is C:\ in your case.  The odds that this directory contains the SampleInputTJU.txt file are low.  The odds that you can create the MyOutputFile.txt in that directory are zero.  Use the CD command to change the default directory, like c:\users\yourname\documents.  Or use full path names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a program, regardless of platform. The format shall be:

```
<Program path> [program arg list]
```

The path can be relative or absolute.

In your Linux shell. You are running:

```
./xyz -l4 -w6 -k4 -iSampleInputTJU.txt -oMyOutputFile.txt -p
```

You are using `./`. This means your program is under current directory.

In your windows console:

```
C:>\Desktop\xyz -l4 -w6 -k4 -iSampleInputTJU.txt -oMyOutputFile.txt -p
```

You are using absolute path here. You might not run the program under the path which your input file locates. You can type `dir` to check the current directory see if the input file is there.